# Filtering data WITHOUT checkboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, search, checkbox, filter

I managed to filter results using jquery and checkboxes. My problem is when I use a style checkbox, it stops working.

Below is my code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
    $('.searchresults >div').fadeOut(500);
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        $('.searchresults  >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']').fadeIn(600);
    });
} else {
    $('.searchresults >div').fadeIn(650);

}
});
```

this works fine when the filter is standard checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="horror" value="horror" /> Horror<br />
```

but fails when this is the code:

```
<input id="drama" type="checkbox" class="icheck" value="" />
```

because the class icheck modifies the html like this:

```
<div class="checkbox theme-search-results-sidebar-section-checkbox-list-item">
                      <label class="icheck-label">
                        <div class="icheck" style="position: relative;"><input class="icheck" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>
                        <span class="icheck-title">EWR: Newark</span>
                      </label>
                      <span class="theme-search-results-sidebar-section-checkbox-list-amount">276</span>
                    </div>
```

can anybody suggest if the same filtering can be achieved by not using checkboxes but using span id's perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `change` event handler instead of click event handler and use `class=icheck` jquery selector for more precise result.

see below code

```
$('input[type="checkbox"].icheck').on('change', function() {
   var $checked = $('input[type="checkbox"].icheck:checked');
   if ($checked.length > 0) {
        $('.searchresults >div').fadeOut(500);
        $checked.each(function() {
           $('.searchresults  >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']').fadeIn(600);
        });
   } else {
      $('.searchresults >div').fadeIn(650);
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work because clicking the checkbox actually doesn't seem to add element "checked" to it. I think they achieve that effect with css. here is what the html of clicked checkbox looks like: <div class="icheck checked" style="position: relative;"><input id="drama" class="icheck" type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;"></ins></div>

Comment: you can see that the div is made too look like it has been checked using the class="icheck checked"

Comment: can you recreate this issue on code snippet? so that i can take a look at it

Comment: it has a lot of dependencies , I cannot recreate it on snippet. I have a workaround instead of listening to checkbox click, I am detecting a click on span and getting the assigned id from the span.   like this:      $('.icheck-title').click(function(event) {
     alert($(event.target).attr("id"));
});